# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'combo_callback'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

После срабатывания кнопки "Комбо" возникает ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\bot_manager1\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6770, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\bot_manager1\main.py", line 810, in combo
    combo.combo_callback(call)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'combo_callback'
```

С другими файлами по типу десерт, пицца и суши проблем нет

```
#main.py
import telebot

from telebot import types
import combo
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

from user import users

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'combo')
def combo(call):
    combo.combo_callback(call)

#combo.py

import telebot
from telebot import types
from user import users
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'combo')
def combo_callback(call):
    markup_8 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Больше мяса - 1380₽ '+ '', callback_data='bolshe_masa')
    markup_8.row(btn1)
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Больше овощей - 1380₽ '+ '', callback_data='bolshe_ovoshei')
    markup_8.row(btn2)
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сет Квадро - 588₽ ' +'', callback_data='set_kvadro')
    markup_8.row(btn3)
    btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сет горячих роллов - 758₽ ' +'', callback_data='set_gor_rolov')
    markup_8.row(btn4)
    btn5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сет Дзен - 998₽ ' +'', callback_data='set_dzen')
    markup_8.row(btn5)
    btn6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сет для друзей - 1088₽ ' +'', callback_data='set_dla_druzei')
    markup_8.row(btn6)
    btn7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Мега хит - 1398₽ ' +'', callback_data='mega_hit')
    markup_8.row(btn7)
    btn8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сет Хватит Всем - 1638₽ ' +'', callback_data='set_hvatit_vsem')
    markup_8.row(btn8)
    btn9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сет Большой Куш - 2298₽ ' +'‍♀', callback_data='set_bolshoi_kush')
    markup_8.row(btn9)
    btn10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сет для Дня Рождения - 2866₽ ' +'', callback_data='set_dla_dnia_rozhdenia')
    markup_8.row(btn10)
    btn11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('⬅'+' Назад', callback_data='menu')
    markup_8.row(btn11)
    photo_url = 'https://img2.rudalle.ru/images/88/72/35/8872356fc01442629b1f8e238985a71d_00000.jpg'
    bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                           media=types.InputMediaPhoto(photo_url), reply_markup=markup_8)
    bot.edit_message_caption(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                             caption='Комбо:', reply_markup=markup_8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел решение проблемы. Нужно было изменить название функции `combo` в `main.py` на другое, чтобы оно не пересекалось с модулем `combo`